# Static scripts output with gulp-rev and gulp-inject: file not injected in clean build

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

The gulpfile.js I wrote is [Common gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/WhaleWatching/bf96355179d95c5daf95).

In a `build` task, `inject` should inject all static files into html outputs, but it inject nothing in the clean build , I must run same command(here is `gulp -p project build`) twice(`gulp -p project build && gulp -p project build`) to inject them successful.

I have tried use [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence), it helps nothing.

Is this a bug?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your gulp tasks appear not to be returning their streams. If you do not return a stream from a task, then any other tasks that depend on it will not wait for the async behaviour to complete before running.

So more or less, what you're seeing is that you have two levels of things that have to happen: first your "script", "style", and "asset" tasks need to be completed, and then when everything's ready your "view" task can do its work. The first time you run it, all four tasks are run at nearly the same time (so "view" runs with old "asset" results, etc.)

To fix it, just return the working stream in each task:

```
gulp.task('style', ['check'], function () {
  var less_filter = gulpFilter('**/*.less');
  return gulp.src(path_current.src_path_style)
             .pipe(less_filter)
             // ... the rest of your pipes
             .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});
```